# Dragboxes in a page (Dashboard kind of display which is clickable)

Tags: blocks

I'm creating a new site and is fairly new to Drupal.
I had some research into sites and liked "http://churchofengland.org/" front page.

They have aligned the front-page with dragboxes.
How can I do similar in Drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [jQuery UI Sortable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) used in the "grid" display mode (this is how the C of E website does it).

As Drupal 7 includes jQuery UI you can add the required libraries like this:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.sortable');
```

And then simlpy add a Javascript file to the required pages with your code in to attach the sortable behaviour to the correct elements. There are plenty of examples on the documentation page to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would check into jQuery UI/Drag & Drop.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/

After you get the hang of this, create a template file for your homepage.
Create blocks with different content and render them in your homepage template file.
Apply the drag and drop interface to the blocks you rendered on your homepage.

This is just a quick look on your question, but it should get you in the right direction.